# Keep mouse and keyboard connected to monitor and switch monitor input between different sources?

Tags: keyboard, display, mouse, external-display

I have a monitor with a Windows PC, a Macbook pro and a Raspberri Pi connected to it's different inputs.

Switching to another source on the monitor works fine when it comes to the display, but it would be nice if I could connect my mouse and keyboard to the monitor and not have to switch them to the device I'm currently using. Is there a way to make this work?

If I have my mouse and keyboard connected to the screen, my Windows PC can use them, but the other devices can not - even if they are the selected source.

Can I make this happen?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You'd have to buy more hardware: a KVM Switch.

If you look at your systems the keyboard and mouse are connected to USB and while you can have more than one video input on the monitor you only have one USB uplink which you can only plug in to one hosting computer at a time.

The KVM Switch would give you one connector to your monitor, keyboard, and mouse, and multiple connections for computers. You would not switch inputs in the monitor but on the KVM.

Note: KVM are designed mostly for servers where latency and resolution are not important. Most of them will not be helpful for video gaming or high resolution work.